# Error using a subset of fields in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using EF 4 for the first time in a WebAPI service. I understand the basics if EF, but its still a bit of a learning curve when I'm used to using ADO.

I only want to return a subset (5) of over 100 fields in the table.

Model (EF Generated):

```
public partial class ITEM_MASTER
{
    public string IM_ITEM_CODE { get; set; }
    public string IM_UPC { get; set; }
    public string IM_SUBDEPARTMENT { get; set; }
    public string IM_DESC { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Get Method in my Controller:

```
// GET api/Products
public IQueryable<ITEM_MASTER> GetProduct()
{
    // return db.ITEM_MASTER;

    return db.ITEM_MASTER.Select(x => new ProductList { ItemCode = x.IM_ITEM_CODE });
}
```

The `return db.ITEM_MASTER` works, but with the .Select method I get the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<JWebAPI.Models.ProductList>'` to
>   `'System.Linq.IQueryable<JWebAPI.Models.ITEM_MASTER>'`. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
public class ProductList
{
    public string ItemCode {get; set;}
}
```

The ProductList class acts as a place holder object, as using the .Select returns a DBQuery not the original object type. I read that this was the ideal way to handle this situation.  I'll add more properties to it when I've got it working. I have a downloaded sample that is structured the same way, and that works.

Is this the best way do do what I need, return only a subset of the EF fields?  How can i resolve the conversion error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the error is quite clear, your method is suppose to return `IQueryable<ITEM_MASTER>` but you are trying to return `'System.Linq.IQueryable<JWebAPI.Models.ProductList>'`.

Since you projected your query's result to `'System.Linq.IQueryable<JWebAPI.Models.ProductList>'` You need to have that as return type.

```
// GET api/Products
public IQueryable<ProductList> GetProduct() //Change return type
{
    // return db.ITEM_MASTER;

    return db.ITEM_MASTER.Select(x => new ProductList { ItemCode = x.IM_ITEM_CODE });
}
```

Since you are selecting only a subset of your original entity, you can't project to entity mapped to a table in Entity framework, that is why you need a place holder class `ProductList`

Comment: You gotta be kidding me.  I'm better than that!! Sometimes you get lost in the details, I was focusing on the LINQ part, didn't even think of the method itself.   Thank you so much.